# Babel / Rollup errors transpiling and bundling ES2017

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollupjs, ecmascript-2017

I'm getting an error transpiling `ES2017` JavaScript (specifically `async/await` functions) into `ES5` using Rollup and Babel:

> Error transforming \src\index.js with 'babel' plugin: Options
>   {"modules":false} passed to
>   \node_modules\babel-preset-es2017\lib\index.js which does not accept
>   options.

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

Naturally, the error goes away if I change the `presets` from `es2017` to `es2015` and comment out the `async/await` code.

Note that while the application uses `ES2017` features (i.e. `async/await`), it is published as an NPM package (as an `ES6 (ES2015)` module) that is later transpiled to generic `ES5 (ES2009)`.

How do I get past this error and get my `ES2017` happily transpiling to `ES5`?

Comment: ES2017 is not ES7.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the actual configuration you provided is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017", {modules: false}
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

You should remove the `{modules: false}` option for `babel-preset-es2017`, which accepts none, as it applies to `babel-preset-es2015`.

Comment: But how? The `{modules:false}` option is being auto-inserted by the transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Target `es2015` in your `.babelrc` file:

```
"presets": [
    "es2015"
 ],
```

and preprocess the `es2017` features by first adding the [Rollup Async functions plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-async), which:

> replaces async functions with generator functions that can run in
>   modern browsers or in most versions of node.js during bundling

Add to your project:

```
npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-async
```

And then insert `async` preprocessing to your `rollup.config.js` plugins array, before `babel()`:

```
import async from 'rollup-plugin-async';

...

plugins: [
        async(),
        babel(babelrc())
],
```

The key insight was found in [this Rollup Github issues thread](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/548), wherein @Victorystick confirms that (as of Oct 10, 2016):

> Rollup currently only targets ES6, although it'll likely get extended
>   to ES7 shortly. For now, if you use >ES6 features, they'll need to be
>   transpiled for Rollup to process them

As async/await are likely to be standardized in the next version of ECMAScript, ES2017 (aka ES8), you'll need an extra plugin to process them before Babel runs.

**NOTE:**

YMMV, but I later received [*AsyncHelper not found* run time Errors](https://github.com/leebyron/rollup-plugin-async/issues/1) using `rollup-plugin-async` on Windows 7, so my solution was to (`npm uninstall --save-dev rollup-plugin-async` and) rollback use of `async/await` in favor of [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) throughout my codebase.